# Apache proxy "404 not Found"

Tags: apache-2.4, proxy

I am trying to use apache proxy to route subdomain to diferent port.
I am using this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName test.domain.com
ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:20003/
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:20003/
ProxyRequests     Off

<Proxy http://localhost:20003/>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxy module is enabled.
When i restart apache and try to acces the website it shows an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache is running.
What am i doing wrong ??

Comment: What is "it", here? Which system is complaining? What do the logs say?